# WFS GeoJSONP layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to open a GeoJSONP file hosted in PostgGIS (GeoServer). Everything is ok, except one file that has 960 features and the following code do not open every features:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/...
service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=pqi_data%3Acentros_saude_4326&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript
```

So I thought that is related with the maxFeatures parameter which by default is 50. I changed to 1000 (because I have 960) but gives an error. So I find that the maximum value is 200. How can I increase this limit?
I try in GeoServer settings but nothing works.

Comment: `maxFeatures` is optional just leave it out - if you are still short of features check the log file to see if there is an error

Comment: In logs folder, the log do not explain : "An empty file so that the NSIS installer will pick up this directory as well". I do not understand what happens.

Comment: then that is not the correct log folder - check `GeoServer Status` page to find your real data directory

Comment: Ok, I find the folder. But the log do not show any error: "2020-06-01 16:26:29,158 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        typeName[0] = {pqi_data.com}hospitais_4326
    maxFeatures = 70
    outputFormat = text/javascript
    resultType = results
    formatOptions = {CALLBACK=handleJson3}
2020-06-01 16:26:29,183 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2020-06-01 16:26:29,176 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON"